# regularizing function under sqrt

Tags: riemann-zeta, divergent-series, regularization

Is it possible to find finite part of $\Sigma^\infty_n\sqrt{n^2 +a^2}$ using something like regularized zeta function?

Comment: Can you recall what the finite part is?

Comment: Zeta function is not finit, but we can find a finite part for it by regularizing it. @mathcounterexamples.net